Horror TV show from 80s or early 90s - man buys balding hair spray from infomercial
80's or early 90's, definitely not later. A man is watching an infomercial on TV for the dark hair spray that covers bald spots. He receives it in the mail and accidentally sprays some in his mouth, or he sprays it on his head and a hair gets in his mouth. It turns out the spray is little worms (aliens perhaps?) and they can be seen in the back of his throat. Could have sworn it was a show based on a Stephen King story (Tales from the Crypt, Tales from the Darkside, Monsters, or another similar short story), but I haven't been able to find it after the first time I watched it. 

Could it be Body Bags? According to the wikipedia article, the show (which aired in 1993) was actually a series of horror story vignettes connected(ish) by "bookend segments" featuring a couple of morgue attendants (played by directors John Carpenter and Tobe Hooper). And wikipedia's description of the second vignette pretty well matches your description of the show you remember:

The first story, "The Gas Station", features Robert Carradine as a
  serial killer, with cameos by Sam Raimi and Wes Craven. "Hair"
  follows Stacy Keach as he receives a botched hair transplant that
  infests him with an alien parasite. "Eye" is another transplant
  story, this time featuring Mark Hamill as a baseball player who loses
  an eye in a car accident and receives a transplant, only to be taken
  over by the personality of the eye's previous owner, a murderous
  misogynist.


YES! I have looked for this for YEARS!! Thanks!!
